# How to make the appearance of one object change based on the state of another one in C# XAML WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, slideshow, rectangles

I have created a slideshow within a series of grids in my main window. In it are currently 4 images. There are 3 columns below the slideshow. Ultimately, I would like to have content within these columns that changes with each slide. For the moment, I am using rectangles to represent the content. I would like the rectangles to change colors as each image is displayed (For example:  when the first image is displayed, the rectangles would be different shades of red; when the second image is displayed, the rectangles would be different shades of blue, etc.). The XAML I used to create the slideshow is:

```
<Image x:Name="myImage" Stretch="Fill" MinHeight="400" MinWidth="500" Margin="5" 

ToolTip="SlideShow!"/>
```

Here is the code-behind:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);
    }

    public event EventHandler Tick;

    private DispatcherTimer tmr = new DispatcherTimer(); //Timer for Slide Show.
    private DispatcherTimer tmrPse = new DispatcherTimer(); //Timer for Pause, Last, and 
          //Next. Gives user time to view selected slide, and then re-starts tmr.

    private List<string> images = new List<string>();

    private int imageIndex = 0;

    void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       tmr.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,2);
       tmr.Tick += new EventHandler(tmr_Tick);
       tmr.Start();

       tmrPse.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
       tmrPse.Tick+= new EventHandler(tmrPse_Tick);

       LoadImages();

       ShowNextImage();

       ShowLastImage();
    }

    private void LoadImages()
    {
        // list the files (includede in the XAP file) here
        images.Add("/Images/AYDAYC.jpg"); //imageIndex = 0
        images.Add("/Images/CNNBert.jpg"); //imageIndex = 1
        images.Add("/Images/rwbjets.jpg"); //imageIndex = 2
        images.Add("/Images/worldmap.jpg"); //imageIndex = 3
    }

    private void ShowNextImage()
    {
        var bi = new BitmapImage(new Uri(images[imageIndex], UriKind.Relative));

        myImage.Source = bi;
        imageIndex = (imageIndex + 1) % images.Count;
    }

    private void ShowLastImage()
    {
        var bi = new BitmapImage(new Uri(images[imageIndex], UriKind.Relative));

        myImage.Source = bi;

        imageIndex = (imageIndex - 1) % images.Count;

        if (imageIndex < 0)
        {
            imageIndex = 3;
        }
     }
```

So far, I have found ways to change the status of a rectangle or object on mouse click, but not in the manner that I have described. I have my slides changing on a timer tick, but I also have buttons to stop the timer and advance, pause, or go back a slide. These click events also start a longer timer that allows the selected slide to stay up for a period of time, after which the original timer starts and the slideshow resumes (which is why I'd like the state of the rectangles to be connected to each slide as opposed to the timer). The buttons and slideshow w ork perfectly. My only problem is how to create the association between the slide images and the rectangles.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, but what you are talking about is easy with an MVVM approach. Perhaps you should learn that pattern and rework your design.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a much simpler way. Since the slides change based on the value of imageIndex, I created a method called BoxColor with an if statement that changes the colors of the boxes based on that value. Then, I call that method in my timer tick event and button click events to advance a slide and go back a slide:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);
    }

    public event EventHandler Tick;        

    private DispatcherTimer tmr = new DispatcherTimer(); //Timer for Slide Show.
    private DispatcherTimer tmrPse = new DispatcherTimer(); //Timer for click events.

    private List<string> images = new List<string>();        

    public int imageIndex =-1; //Determines which slide to show.        

    void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tmr.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
        tmr.Tick += new EventHandler(tmr_Tick);

        tmrPse.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
        tmrPse.Tick += new EventHandler(tmrPse_Tick);

        LoadImages();

        tmr.Start();
    }

    private void LoadImages()
    {
        // list the files (includede in the XAP file) here
        images.Add("/Images/AYDAYC.jpg"); //imageIndex = 0
        images.Add("/Images/CNNBert.jpg"); //imageIndex = 1
        images.Add("/Images/rwbjets.jpg"); //imageIndex = 2
        images.Add("/Images/worldmap.jpg"); //imageIndex = 3
    }

    private void ShowNextImage()
    {
        imageIndex = (imageIndex + 1) % images.Count;

        var bi = new BitmapImage(new Uri(images[imageIndex], UriKind.Relative));

        myImage.Source = bi;
    }

    private void ShowLastImage()
    {
        imageIndex = (imageIndex - 1);

        if (imageIndex < 0)
        {
            imageIndex = 3;
        }

        var bi = new BitmapImage(new Uri(images[imageIndex], UriKind.Relative));

        myImage.Source = bi;
    }

    private void BoxColor()
    {
        if (imageIndex == 3)
        {
            LftRct.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
            MidRct.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.SpringGreen);
            RtRct.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.PaleGreen);
        }

        else if (imageIndex == 2)
        {
            LftRct.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
            MidRct.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.RoyalBlue);
            RtRct.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.SkyBlue);
        }

        else if (imageIndex == 1)
        {
            LftRct.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
            MidRct.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Silver);
            RtRct.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.SlateGray);
        }

        else
        {
            LftRct.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            MidRct.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Tomato);
            RtRct.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Pink);
        }            
    }

    void tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShowNextImage();
        BoxColor();
    }

    void tmrPse_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                      
        tmr.Start();
    }

    private void btnLast_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tmr.Stop();
        tmrPse.Start();
        ShowLastImage();
        BoxColor();                      
    }

    private void btnPause_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        tmr.Stop();
        tmrPse.Start();                       
    }       

    private void btnNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tmr.Stop();
        tmrPse.Start();
        ShowNextImage();
        BoxColor();
     }
```

I will probably switch the logic to a switch to make it a bit neater. This has been a good exercise in learning custom event handlers, though.

Comment: Ouch man! You are making it needlessly complex. WPF is really all about databinding and you seem to have thrown the whole concept of my answer away... :(

Comment: Complex? This way is easier to me.
Probably because my first language is C++ and this Mir closely resembles that, but I struggled with your way for days and couldn't get it to work at all. I got the idea to do it this way, and it worked instantly. I've also added more functionality since then. Potayto, potahto, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Binding` on the background color of the rectangles. In your code behind keep track of the index of the currently displayed Image Index with a private backing field and a public getter and setter. The code behind should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to trigger `DataBinding`. Your `DataContext` should be set to this. So the `DataContext` of the page is the page itself (that way you can bind to a property on the page, in fact CurrentImageIndex or so). And then you use a `ValueConverter` on the binding of the background color of the rectangle.

Some pseudo-code:

```
Public class MainWindow: Page, INotifyPropertyChanged

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
  {
      PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
      if (handler != null)
      {
          handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
      }
  }

private Int16 _currentImageIndex;
public Int16 CurrentImageIndex{
  get{return _currentImageIndex;} 
  set
  {
    _currentImageIndex = value; 

    // fire PropertyChangedEventHandler
    OnPropertyChanged("CurrentImageIndex");
  }
}

public MainWindow()
{
  this.DataContext = this;
}

public class ImageIndexConverter: ValueConverter
{
  Convert
  {
    switch(value)
    {
      case 0: return Colors.Red;
      case 1: return Colors.Blue;
      //etc.
    }
  }

  ConvertBack
  {
    return null;
  }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Rectangle BackgroundColor={Binding Path=CurrentImageIndex, Converter={StaticResource ImageIndexConverter}}/>
```

Not tested the code but I hope the concept becomes clear to you. Have a look at the concepts of INotifyPropertyChanged and ValueConverter.

Comment: The suggestion by BradleyDotNET is a good one as well but maybe too complex/ heavy-weight for the situation at the moment.

Comment: Yes, this is quite helpful! After I posted this question, a colleague of mine suggested a similar solution.

Comment: Glad to hear :) Good luck!